# Trying to use twitter API using scribe jar

Tags: java, twitter, scribe

I want to write code in java to get users all "following user-id" information from twitter I have searched a lot and find out scribe library to use twitter API. I have downloaded scribe jar and included in my eclipse java project, My problem is when i am trying to run following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;

public class TwitterExample
{
  private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com  /1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
// If you choose to use a callback, "oauth_verifier" will be the return value by      Twitter (request param)
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                            .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                            .apiKey("6icbcAXyZx67r8uTAUM5Qw")
                            .apiSecret("SCCAdUUc6LXxiazxH3N0QfpNUvlUy84mZ2XZKiv39s")
                            .build();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("=== Twitter's OAuth Workflow ===");
System.out.println();

// Obtain the Request Token
System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
 System.out.print(">>");
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
System.out.println();

// Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
System.out.println();

// Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
request.addBodyParameter("status", "this is sparta! *");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(response.getBody());

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");
}

}
```

I know this code is not about getting "following-user id" information actually this code is available on following link as a runnable example of scribe and in some places I have to fill my keys.

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java

when I am running above code I am getting following error:

=== Twitter's OAuth Workflow ===

Fetching the Request Token...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.doSign(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:47)
    at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.getSignature(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:33)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getSignature(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:122)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:63)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:43)
    at assignment.TwitterExample.main(TwitterExample.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
please help.

Comment: please provide the classpath you use when you start your program. The exception states that one of the apache commons libaries might be missing from the classpath.

Comment: I haven't provided any class path explicitly. I have created a project in eclipse and trying to run this code.

Comment: please check if the scribe documentation indicates the libraries needed for running. If yes, those have to be added to eclipse

Comment: ok I will check it out now.